# Missing Dependencies and Foreign Key Constraint - SQLCompare Red gate

Tags: sql-server, redgate, sqlcompare

We use SQL Compare 11.6.11.2463 to move our database changes to different environments. When we doing that we notices that Table definitions were changes and Foreign Key Constraint was altered where the data in the table was not correct. I have a question here that why the constraint were modified without giving an error that data is bad for that constraint and it should have error while deploying that Foreign Key Constraint.

Second Question is, When we are seeing the dependencies of a table, it does not show all the procedures that table is referenced and used. We are missing the dependencies when we right click on a table and see View Dependencies. Is something changed by the use of SQL Compare as we are not seeing Dependencies.

Comment: For your first question, can you post a sample of the SQL that gets generated along with some data that wasn't correct? For your second issue, I'd suggest contacting Red Gate support.

Comment: SQL Compare is just using the sys.sysdepends view to report dependencies, just like what happens when you right click the item in object explorer. This means that sql server is where the dependency is not showing up. But if you think there are problems with SQL Compare you should consult with the vendor. The people at SO can't help you there.